# How to change the brightness of the Galaxy A10s flashlight

Tags: samsung, android-11, camera-flash, samsung-one-ui, flashlight

I saw how this application ([Cardiograph](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macropinch.hydra.android)) uses a bright flashlight, and then it switches to a dim one. The phone itself (Samsung Galaxy A10s) does not have a built-in flash brightness control, and there is no root either. So, how can you adjust the power of a flashlight, what applications are there for this (maybe even somehow through Termux)? Samsung Galaxy A10s phone, Android 11, all updates installed.

---

[Video](https://youtu.be/B1TyDSkukOs)

Comment: I assume the app is simulating dimming by letting the LED flicker in a high frequency.

Comment: @Robert No, the LED does not blink in any way, it is a static light.

Comment: You will see blinking only if the frequency is low. If it is higher than 100 Hz humans will not recognize it as blinking. But I am not sure if you can switch the led so many times a second.

Comment: Adjusting flashlight brightness is a new feature in Android 13. On Android 12 and older there is no universally working solution. Some app developers tried to *"misuse"* [flash modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getFlashMode()) and [preview mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#startPreview()), while others tried to write directly to `/sys/class/leds/`. None is guaranteed to work on all devices. Except that the OEM or custom ROM developer has already added the option in Settings.

Comment: And I just checked. The app you've mentioned uses the both APIs: flash mode and preview mode. The latter seems to [do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20421672/9165920) on Samsung devices.

Answer (score 1):

From googling, I found [How to adjust the flashlight brightness on your Samsung Galaxy phone](https://www.androidpolice.com/how-to-adjust-the-flashlight-brightness-on-your-samsung-galaxy-phone/);

> 3. **Tap the word “Flashlight“** below the icon to open the brightness slider.
> 4. Alternatively, you can **long-press the Flashlight icon** itself to access it.
> 5. **Adjust the slider** from Level 1 to Level 5 as you desire.
> 6. After choosing a brightness level, tap **Done** to leave the setting.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy A10s doesn't have this option.

Comment: I found that too, but I wonder if instead or torch he means flash for taking pictures